# Is my eval() safe?

Tags: javascript, regex, security, xss

I built a dice roller here: http://howderek.com/projects/diediedie/

and I wanted to implement math so that my users could preform mathmatical operations to their rolls, which is useful for RPGs.

Instead of building a function to handle the math, or using a library like *math.js*, I figured that since JavaScript has math built in, this might be a good use for `eval()`.

The reason I am concerned with the `eval()` however, is that appending `?q=whatever` to the url of DieDieDie enters `whatever` into the box and passed it to DieDieDie

Now, obviously, if this was purely just an eval console, it would be easy to abuse and run malicious JavaScript through, but it's not, I use a RegEx before running `eval()`

From (http://howderek.com/projects/diediedie/js/diediedie.js):

```
if (!replaced.match(/[^0-9 | + | \- | * | \/ | ( | ) | \. | % | > | <]/g)) {
    result = eval(replaced);
} else {
    throw 'Unsafe eval (more than just math), refusing to execute.';
}
```

So, I was wondering if there was any way to circumvent the RegEx, and run code though that `eval()` just by entering text into the box.

Comment: As safe a gun with 9 bullets :)

Comment: You'll never be able to get this perfect, and certainly not with RegEx.  Consider a JavaScript sandbox at best.

Comment: Good thing I have `/* jslint evil:true */`

Comment: you can safely lock down eval in strict mode, but not without it...

Comment: It is in strict mode. That doesn't make it safe however, it can still edit `document`

Comment: http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

Comment: @Prinzhorn, that code will not execute, square brackets are not allowed.

Comment: not if you make document, window, etc private, chop constructor off of Function.prototype, and so on. can anyone find a hole in http://danml.com/js/subeval.js ? (haven't heard of one yet..) one caveat: make sure to throw is strict is not supported.

Comment: @howderek of course, but the point was to think outside of the box.

Comment: @Prinzhorn thank you, I just don't know if I should be concerned or not. I mean, no matter what, this will be at least as secure as bit.ly, because I host nothing but the js, someone would have to click on a malicious link in order to be attacked, but I would prefer it if my site could not be used for such things.

Comment: you can also use a worker to prevent global code modification in your app and to prevent the display of ads, removing the carrot.

Comment: Please note that your expression also allows the character `|`. `|` is not the alternation character in a character class. Your expression would just be: `/[^0-9+\-*\/().%><]/g`

Comment: @howderek it's your decision if you take the risk or not. All we can say is that you can't make this foolproof. You could write a grammar and validate it though, i.e. with http://pegjs.majda.cz/ or similar.

Comment: without letters or a backslash, i'm going to go out on a limb and call it safe. i'll happily pay $20 for code that pops an alert after passing the regexp from Felix. Any takers?

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, that is very helpful. I wish I could give you more than a comment upvote for that.

@Prinzhorn That parser library actually looks really kick ass, thanks! Although I still think this is secure, I just don't know 100% so that's why I asked SO, and as I said I don't want an external library if I don't need one

@dandavis Felix's RegExp actually won't work for me, but I did use his suggestion, use this one: `/[^0-9+\-*\/()\.%>< ]/g` but I would second that $20 bet, if I wasn't too broke to be making $20 bets

Comment: Seems to be much easier to claim "as safe as a gun with 9 bullets", "certainly not with RegEx", "can't make this foolproof", etc, than it is for such detractors to demonstrate even a single point of failure.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed the space in my expression ;)

Comment: Look into the shunting yard algorithm. You can come up with variation without functions. Treat `d` as a unary, high precedence operator with RtL associativity that yields a random number in the range specified by its only associated token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complexity is the enemy of security, so I find it best to implement a simple solution that you *know* is secure rather than attempting to come up with something more complicated that has *possibly* made something safe (but no one is quite sure until an exploit is found).

A safe way to do it is that you could use a [HTML5 Sandbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) to load a page hosting your script, then you do not need to be concerned about whether your RegEx can be bypassed.

You will need to host the page under a different domain than your main site (e.g. `script.example.com` instead of `www.example.com`). This will prevent any [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attack if an attacker convinces a user to visit the page directly (outside of the sandbox).

You will need to enable scripts within the IFrame by using code like this:

`<iframe src="http://script.example.com/projects/diediedie/" sandbox="allow-scripts" />`

This will allow scripts, but in the case of an exploit being found to your RegEx, forms and navigation outside of the IFrame will be prevented. As it is on a different domain, your main site cannot be attacked via [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

The [HTML5 Security Cheat Sheet guidance on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Sandboxed_frames) states this is the purpose of the sandbox:

> Use the sandbox attribute of an iframe for untrusted content

As you are allowing untrusted content to run via `eval` (albeit "sanitised" via RegEx), this seems like an appropriate use of the sandboxed IFrame.

You should test whether sandbox is supported first, before rendering the IFrame:

`<iframe src="/blank.htm" sandbox="allow-scripts" id="foo" />`

```
var sandboxSupported = "sandbox" in document.createElement("iframe");

if (sandboxSupported) {
    document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('src', 'http://script.example.com/projects/diediedie/');
}
else
{
    // Not safe to display IFrame
}
```

It is safer to do it this way by dynamically changing the `src` rather than redirecting away if `sandboxSupported` is `false` because then the iframe will not accidentally be rendered if the redirect doesn't happen in time.

To enable this to work cross-domain (between `script.example.com` and `www.example.com`) you will need to use HTML5's [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage) functionality. This will enable secure communication between the IFrame and the outer window. Note that setting [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.domain) is not secure as it will defeat the purpose of hosting the page on a separate domain in the first place.