# Is it safe to declare critical literals in "with (...) {...}" to sandbox code run within it?

Tags: javascript, security, sandbox, code-injection, with-statement

I avoid using `eval()` or Functions created from a string. But when I need to run some subset of Javascript that can be entered by a user I'm tempted to use it just because it will save me much work writing a lexer/parser and interpreter.

Say I'd like to run this code:

```
a.toLowerCase() === 'xyz' || b == 1 || /pqr/.test(c)
```

the native approach would be to pass it into `eval()` like this:

```
with({a: ..., b: ..., c: ...}) {
    ret = eval(code);
}
```

I cannot be sure that `code` always contains uncritical code like the above. This opens the possibilities to run malicious code.

I thought of passing an object re-defining critical Browser objects to `with` besides the actual data like:

```
var obj = {
   // list incomplete ;)
   console: true, XMLHttpRequest: true, document: true, window: true, addEventListener: true, removeEventListener: true, parent: true, top: true, history: true, ..., 

   // actual data
   a: ..., b: ..., c: ...
};

with (obj) {
   ...
}
```

When running code within `with` access to the objects/methods is not possibe.

I know that it's still possible to indirectly access those methods if they are indirectly accessed though another object/function that is not re-defined. Let's assume I re-define these too.

Is it secure to sandbox code with a *suffient list* of objects and functions as content object?

What would be remaining the attack vectors in this case?

## Edit 1:

The code should run within Firefox, Chrome, IE (10+), Opera, Safari.

Comment: Where is it running? In the user's own browser? In NodeJS? In NodeJS or modern browsers, you'll have better luck using in IIFE with strict mode.

Comment: Just let every user run its own code in his own browser. Nothing can go wrong there.

Comment: [A possible solution for sandboxing code (this is a link)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21700111/413180).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not secure.

No matter what you do with your code's execution environment using `with`, it is still possible to retrieve the "real" global object using the following trick:

```
var window = (function(){ return this }).call(undefined);
```

This works because `Function.call` will use the global object as the value of `this` if it is explicitly passed as `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: They don't even need `.call()`. Just `(function(){ return this })()` will do the same.

Comment: Couldn't that be resolved by removing any `function` from the string being `eval`-uated?

Comment: @AlexisWilke: No. Blacklisting bad code never works well. I mean, the next step would be `var window = (1,eval)("this");`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke … and even then, you'd still be preventing your users' code from containing any functions. That's a rather serious limitation.

Comment: @duskwuff, depends what you want to allow in that `eval()`. From the example given in the question, it looks like *simple* expressions, which should never require support for inline functions.

Answer (score 4):

If the shadowed variables were deleted ...

```js
alert([1, window, document]);

var obj = {
    document: true, window: true
};

with (obj) {
  alert([2, window, document]);
  
  delete window;
  delete document;
  
  alert([3, window, document]); //restored
}
```

Additionally if you exposed any DOM elements the `document`/`window` objects could be reached via `ownerDocument`/`defaultView`.

Comment: Couldn't this be resolve by removing any `delete` from the string being `eval`-uated?

Comment: You would need to deal with all possibilities of things like `eval("de" + "lete document");`, if you replace `eval` you would need to prohibit `new function` evaluation ... its a zero sum game you can't win.

Comment: However, one could make the variables safe against `delete`ing by defining them as non-configurable.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of a global (and "static") function to avoid giving access to other unwanted/private variables (i.e. a sub-function has access to all the variables of the parent function).

Second you want to remove a few keywords from the string to be evaluated to avoid problems as described by duskwuff and Alex K. Something like this:

```
function exec(e)
{
    e = e.replace(/new/, "new_", "g")
         .replace(/delete/, "delete_", "g")
         .replace(/function/, "function_", "g")
         .replace(/throw/, "throw_", "g")
         .replace(/this/, "this_", "g")
         .replace(/var/, "var_", "g")
         .replace(/eval/, "eval_", "g");
    obj = { ... };
    with(obj)
    {
        eval(e);
    }
}
```

Note that may not work in strict mode. As mentioned by Bergi in a comment, you could also protect the variables in `obj` and make them non-deletable so you cannot replace them.

The `replace()` can include many more things... you may want to look closer at what you are trying to achieve. If the evaluation string is expected to just be an expression, then all keywords should be removed (Except `true` and `false` and `null`). You may also want to remove a few other functions. Here I only removed `eval`.

If you'd like to only match words so the word `anew` does not match `new` you can use the [`\b` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) in the regex. I do not know how compatible this flag is across browsers.

```
e.replace(/\bnew\b/, "new_", "g");
```

This would match `new` but not `anew`.

Comment: What if a string contains the substring "new", "delete", ...?

Comment: Then you probably won't get the correct results. You can always tell the end users that those keywords are forbidden. You could also fix the regex's.

Comment: I did an update, it is likely that the `\b` does not work in all browsers, though.